# jquery validator.methods.number and comma instead of dot in number

Tags: regex, validation

I found this nice tutorial for checking numbers if instead of dot comma's are used

http://blog.degree.no/2013/04/decimal-validation-with-comma-in-mvc/

```
$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {        
        return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:d+|d{1,3}(?:[s.,]d{3})+)(?:[.,]d+)?$/.test(value);
    };
```

but this regex

```
/^-?(?:d+|d{1,3}(?:[s.,]d{3})+)(?:[.,]d+)?$/.test(value)
```

always return `false`.

For example value `5` is `false`

what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\.,]\d{3})+)(?:[\.,]\d+)?$/.test(value);
```